# Copied charts not visible in Excel Online

Tags: excel, sharepoint, charts, sharepoint-online

I'm not a very experienced Excel use but I'm having a weird issue with charts not showing up in `Excel Online`. I have a workbook (xlsx) with a few different example charts. These charts should be used for different data ranges in the same workbook and because of this I copy/pasted the example chart and changed the data ranges for new copy. I then uploaded the document to a SharePoint Online library to be able to show the charts as images (through `ExcelRest.aspx`).

When I open the the Excel document in the desktop version of Excel everything looks alright and I can see the charts with the correct values. However, when I try to open the file in Excel Online I can only see the example chart and not the copied version?

By using the `/Model/Charts` functionality of `ExcelRest.aspx` I can see the charts in the model, but when I try to access it through it's url I instead get the unmodified example chart?

I can create a chart from scratch and make it show up, but since there are quite a few different charts that should be created it would take a lot of time to create them from scratch.

Does anyone know what's going on, it seems really strange to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I think I've found a work around for this issue which seems to solve it for me. I tried fiddling around with every setting I could find and what finally seemed to solve it was to move the "invisible" chart to it's own data sheet (right click on the chart, select "Move chart" and "new sheet").

It's a bit harder to get a quick overview of the charts now but at least it works. If somebody could shed some light on this strange behavior it would be greatly appreciated!